# Castle Windsor Interceptors and Registering by Convention

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, interceptor

I'm currently using Castle Windsor to manage dependencies for my application.

I'm currently using the `Classes.FromAssemblyContaining` to register all components of a given type `IFoo<>` and would like to register an interceptor for all of these classes.

I can get the interceptor to work when I register individual components like this:

```
public void SetUpContainer(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>()
                                .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
                                .LifestyleSingleton().Interceptors<MyIntercepter>());
}
```

However I would like to keep registering by convention using Classes.FromAssembly. My registration code currently looks something like this:

```
public void SetUpContainer(IWindsorContainer container)
{
     container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<Foo>()
                               .BasedOn(typeof(IFoo<>))
                               .WithService.Base());
}
```

How would I add an interceptor for all `IFoo<>`'s that are registered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use the `Configure` method to add the interceptor:

```
public void SetUpContainer(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<Foo>()
                              .BasedOn(typeof(IFoo<>))
                              .WithService.Base()
                              .Configure(r => r.Interceptors<FooInterceptor>()));
}
```

I also needed to register the interceptor:

```
container.Register(Component.For<FooInterceptor>());
```

But presumably you'd be registering this elsewhere (by convention).